# scale uploaded image from canvas on webserver with php

Tags: php, javascript, scale, fabricjs, imagecreatefrompng

my issue is to upload the current canvas not only as a JSON Object in my Database, I also want to save a thumbnail from the canvas. It is for a kind of layout gallery.

Nearly everything is working except the scale to e specific size.
I used this Tutorial for the PHP function `function scaleImg();` [Scale Image with PHP](http://oswaldatwork.thetaoofamp.com/2009/10/scaling-images-in-php-done-right/)

So here is my Code from the upload script:
layoutupload.php

```
...
    //Save canvas as thumbnail


 //datafields
     $lt_dir = "../flyer/templateDATA/template_1_thumbs/";
     $lt_canvas_thumb = $_POST['lt_canvas_thumb'];

     //delete header
     $lt_canvas_thumb = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,','', $lt_canvas_thumb);
     $lt_canvas_thumb = str_replace(' ', '+', $lt_canvas_thumb);

     //decode to an image
     $img_data = base64_decode($lt_canvas_thumb);
     $file = $lt_dir.'tmp.png';

     //save in filesystem
     $success = file_put_contents($file, $img_data);
     print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';

     //scale img with helper class
     include "helper_scaleImg.php";
     scaleImg($file,100,141,'png'); // ($img,$width,$height,$type)
...
```

This `var lt_canvas_thumb = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` comes from a JavaScript function

I can save the image on the filesystem but only with the original canvas dimensions (370x522).
Here is the PHP script for scaling

```
function scaleImg($img, $width, $height, $type){

//$type = exif_imagetype($img);
//Possible types
//IMAGETYPE_JPEG
//IMAGETYPE_PNG

if($type == 'jpg'){

    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);

    // Get the size of img
    $source_imagex = imagesx($source_image); //width
    $source_imagey = imagesy($source_image); //height

    // destination image
    $dest_imagex = $width;
    $dest_imagey = $height;
    $dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);

    //best quality (slow)
    imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);

    return imagejpeg($dest_image,NULL,100);


}
else if($type == 'png'){

    $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($img);

    if(!$source_image){
        // Get the size of img
        $source_imagex = imagesx($source_image); //width
        $source_imagey = imagesy($source_image); //height

        // destination image
        $dest_imagex = $width;
        $dest_imagey = $height;
        $dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);

        //best quality (slow)
        imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);

        /* Output an error message */
        imagestring($source_image, 1, 5, 5, 'Error loading ' . $img);
    }

    return imagepng($dest_image,NULL,9);
    //return $dest_image;
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid image type!";
    exit;
}
```

}

I'm getting the following error message:

> Data: 
>   ../flyer/templateDATA/template_1_thumbs/tmp.png
>   **Warning**:  imagepng() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/flyer/helper_scaleImg.php** on line **57**

I don't know why it's "null", because the File is correctly saved in my directory.
I hope it issn't a small mistake in my code, and I hope someone can help me. 
Thanks!
Greetings Max

Answer (score 1):

`if(!$source_image)` is evaluating to false if the source image loads, and so the block of code that defines `$dest_image` is being skipped.

Comment: Ok without this block, I'm getting a message with this:<br> `IHDRd���HI�IDATx����sGz���3����� �$DQ�ˇd[���ҮwsTj�<�!�X�a���u�v����iY� �2�C$���`�< J��*�HJd�W,�`@0����z�a�av�!��E#V{��*����BZ�Z��� ���H�N���F����㠉�s�/��(4����X���SW>�h�U��L\����lN��Oڵ�p��w��$;{�~�o���Bg���1�
B��k�f8c�����.^����Wgs�V�;P4camǦM���E�~��#胈��,g�t���04U~��/�r���;8~�V.x��$IU�[3���vGǦ�# �Q+~�����ru!���lu�O_�NY������B���P,92Y��AR�r!}�SMU�ԈV|pBhV����wJm` <br> This looks like the base64 data. And the image is save in the directory with the "old" dimensions.

Comment: Can you post your updated code? That looks like PNG image data output as text.  If you're sending this to a browser, you'll need to output the correct content-type header.

Comment: Hi, I could solve my Problem. I scaled the image indeed, but I didn't saved it to the directory. In "scaleImg(...)" return imagejpeg($dest_image,$jpg_dest_url,100); The $jpg_dest_url with the right url solved the problem. At the beginning I just used NULL for this parameter. Greetings Max